# How to index files while uploading on google drive and then search using indexing?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Is it possible to index file content during upload to drive and later search against it using Google API?
In this way it should be faster. Also, I am thinking to extract contend (using vision) and use it to search later via search APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The search function for [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) response is very limited.  You cant [search on all the fields](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref) so unless you want to add some special tag to the name of the file i dont think there is anyway your going to be able to index them for faster searching.

Comment: google cloud api is not the google drive api they are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You need to duplicate the file content and set it as `contentHints.indexableText` within your POST body.

From https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

> contentHints.indexableText    string  Text to be indexed for the file to improve fullText queries. This is limited to 128KB in length and may contain HTML elements.